# how to style and format a zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

i was wondering how to style a zend form:

```
// Pants
    $this->addElement('select', 'waistmin', array(
            'label' => 'Pants: ',
            'multiOptions' => array_merge(array(''=>'', 'Any'=>'Any'),array_combine(range(21, 48), range(21, 48)) ),
            'value' => 'Any'
    ));

    $this->addElement('select', 'waistmax', array(
            'label' => 'to: ',
            'multiOptions' => array_merge(array(''=>'', 'Any'=>'Any'),array_combine(range(21, 48), range(21, 48)) ),
            'value' => 'Any'
    ));

    // Bust & Chest
    $this->addElement('select', 'bustmin', array(
            'label' => 'Bust & Chest: ',
            'multiOptions' => array_merge(array(''=>'', 'Any'=>'Any'),array_combine(range(30, 50), range(30, 50)) ),
            'value' => 'Any'
    ));

    $this->addElement('select', 'bustmax', array(
            'label' => 'to: ',
            'multiOptions' => array_merge(array(''=>'', 'Any'=>'Any'),array_combine(range(30, 50), range(30, 50)) ),
            'value' => 'Any'
    ));
```

i have this form in a form.php and i place in in my view file by using `echo $this->form;`

i know that i can add style tags and id tags, but what i want it so position them better.

right now they come one after each other:

```
Pants:
   <drip down>
to:
   <drip down>
Bust & Chest:
   <drip down>
to:
   <drip down>
```

i want to group the together in divs or maybe in a table:

```
Pants:               to:
   <drip down>           <drip down>

Bust & Chest:               to:
   <drip down>           <drip down>
```

if i echo html inside the form it will not render inside my page.

any ideas on what approach i can take?

thans

Comment: Instead of echo'ing $this->form, try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262) you will have much more control over the look and feel of your form.

Comment: nice, this might work. add this as an answer and ill check it as the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have more control over how and where individual form elements are displayed, you can output individual form elements and wrap them in html as you see fit.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262).  This answer on [splitting up a zend form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811737/splitting-up-a-zend-form/7813651#7813651) may help you as well as it shows how to remove decorators from the select element so it isn't wrapped in any html which will work well with the example below.

Instead of doing `echo $this->form;` you can do something like the following:

```
<div class="form-sel">
Pants: <?php echo $this->form->waistmin ?> to: <?php echo $this->form->waistmax ?>
</div>

<div class="form-sel">
Bust &amp; Chest: <?php echo $this->form->bustmin ?> to: <?php echo $this->form->bustmax ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Аccording zend documentation you should use decorators to change markup of your form elements, also try $form->render() insetad echo.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply do CSS for the dl, dt and dd Zend Forms use. That will allow you to modify their styling